# How do you stop Android Studio from removing imports when you add a java comment block into your code?

Tags: android-studio

I am using the following version of Android Studio

```
Android Studio 3.3
Build #AI-182.5107.16.33.5199772, built on December 25, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Mac OS X 10.11.6
```

This and the previous version have an annoying habit of removing some of your imports when you add a comment to your Java code.

It is an intermittent "feature", annoying none the less.

Is there any way I can stop it from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following trick should do the work for you,

1. Goto File -> Settings -> Editor
2. Select General tab
3. Select Auto Import - Java (language)
4. Disable  **Optimize imports on the fly** by unchecking it.
5. Click on OK button